# How to perform a left join with an additional filtering in LINQ to entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have several tables, the main one is called `DefectRecord`, others are called `DefectArea`, `DefectLevel`...etc and the one called `DefectAttachment`. And this problem is about joining `DefectRecord` with other tables to get a ViewModel for further use. What the hard part I am facing is about the `DefectAttachment` table.

`DefectRecord` has a 1-to-many relation with `DefectAttachment`. While there may be NO attachment at all for one defect record, there may be multiple attachments.

Logically I tried to perform a left join among `DefectRecord` & `DefectAttachment`, but there is one more requiredment:

- If there is multiple attachments, select ONLY the oldest one(i.e. the
  one with oldest `CreatedDate` field value)

I am stuck at this requirement, **how can I perform this with LINQ-to-Entities**? Below is the code of what I have now:

```
 var ret = (from dr in defectRecordQuery
            join ft in filterQuery on dr.FilterID equals ft.FilterID
            join l in levelQuery on dr.LevelID equals l.LevelID
            join a in attachmentQuery on dr.DefectRecordID equals a.DefectRecordID into drd  
            from g in drd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new DefectRecordViewModel
            {
                DefectRecordCode = dr.Code,
                DefectAttachmentContent = g == null ? null : g.FileContent,
                LookupFilterName = ft.FilterName,
            }).ToList();
```

The *Query variable are the `IQueryable` object which get the full list of corresponding table.

Comment: Changing `from g in drd.DefaultIfEmpty()` to `from g in drd.DefaultIfEmpty().OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).Take(1)` should be sufficient

Comment: @IvanStoev - was about to change it in the `select` part and add the `Take(1)` but didn't think of it in the `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your results by the `Code` and `FilterName` and then for the content take that of the item in the group that has the oldest date

```
var ret = (from dr in defectRecordQuery
            join ft in filterQuery on dr.FilterID equals ft.FilterID
            join l in levelQuery on dr.LevelID equals l.LevelID

            join d in attachmentQuery on dr.DefectRecordID equals d.DefectRecordID into drd
            from g in drd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group g by new { dr.Code, ft.FilterName } into gg

            select new DefectRecordViewModel
            {
                DefectRecordCode = gg.Key.Code,
                DefectAttachmentContent = gg.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDateTime).FirstOrDefault() == null? null: gg.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDateTime).FirstOrDefault().FileContent,
                LookupFilterName = gg.Key.FilterName,
            }).ToList();
```

If using C# 6.0 or higher then you can do:

```
DefectAttachmentContent = gg.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDateTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault()?.FileContent,
```

Comment: @shole - Oh great :) was afraid it won' because couldn't really test it :)

Comment: did change your code a bit, but that gave me a correct direction :)!

Comment: Thanks for the C# 6.0 info..No wonder I did not work (and stupidly think that's your typo...) thanks very much